# VBA- creating a user defined function

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a function, which would return the expected value of a distribution for the given duration.
The input will be in the following format only
ExpValue(Jan--01/June30;EXPO(2000),July--01/Dec--31;NORM(1000,2000))
where the Jan--01/June30 and July--01/Dec--31 are the duration.
And, EXPO(2000) and NORM(1000,2000) are the type of distribution (with mean, std deviation, etc provided in the parenthesis) of the data for that particular season. The user has to input only starting 4 letter for the type of distribution, like:
NORM for NORMAL distribution
EXPO for EXPONENTIAL distribution, etc.
There can be as many seasons as possible, separated by"," and the type of duration for each season is mentioned respectively separated from the duration by ";".

I have written the code for the function, but it is not working. Please suggest me the required changes.

```
Public Function ExpValue(str As String) As String

Dim Mylen As Integer
Dim A As Integer
Dim B As Integer
Dim C As Integer
Dim D As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim k As Integer
Dim l As Double
Dim N As Integer
Dim ExpectValue As Double
Dim Arr1() As String
Dim Arr2() As String
Dim Arr3() As String
Dim Arr4() As String
Dim Arr5() As String
Dim Arr6() As String
Dim Arr7() As Double
Dim txt1 As String
Dim txt2 As String
Dim txt3 As String
Dim txt4 As String
Dim txt5 As String
Dim txt6 As String

Arr1() = Split(str, ",")
C = UBound(Arr1())
ReDim Arr1(C) As String

    For i = 0 To C

            Arr2() = Split(Arr1(i), ";")
            ReDim Arr2(1) As String
            Arr3(i) = Arr2(0)
            Arr4(i) = Arr2(1)

    Next i

    ReDim Arr3(C) As String
    ReDim Arr4(C) As String

    For i = 0 To C
        txt1 = Arr4(i)
        Mylen = Len(txt1)
        txt2 = Left(txt1, 4)        ' type of distribution
        A = Mylen - 5
        B = Mylen - 6
        txt3 = Right(txt1, A)       ' 1,2.3,4,... )
        txt4 = Left(txt3, B)        ' 1,2.3,4.,..
        Arr5 = Split(txt4, ",")
        D = UBound(Arr5())

        ReDim Arr7(D) As Double
            For j = 0 To D
                Arr7(i) = CDbl(Arr5(i))
            Next j

        Select Case txt2

            Case "EXPO", "POIS"             ' just one number EXPO(2.34)
            l = CDbl(txt4)                  ' txt4=2.34
            Arr6(i) = l

            Case "NORM"
            ExpectValue = Arr7(1)
            Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

            Case "BETA"
            ExpectValue = (Arr7(1) / (Arr7(0) + Arr7(1)))
            Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

            Case "GAMM"
            ExpectValue = Arr7(0) * Arr7(1)
            Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

            Case "TRIA"
            ExpectValue = ((Arr7(0) + Arr7(1) + Arr7(2)) / 3)
            Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

            Case "UNIF"
            ExpectValue = ((Arr7(0) + Arr7(1)) / 2)
            Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

            Case "LOGN"
            ExpectValue = Exp((Arr7(0) + ((Arr7(1)) ^ 2)) / 2)
            Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

            Case "ERLA"
            ExpectValue = Arr7(0) * Arr7(1)
            Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

        End Select

    'Next j
    Next i
    'i = i + 1

    If C = 0 Then
        txt6 = Arr3(0) & ";" & Arr6(0)
    Else
        txt6 = ""

        For i = 0 To C
            txt6 = txt6 & "," & Arr3(i) & "," & Arr6(i)
        Next i

    End If

    ExpValue = txt5

End Function
```

Comment: Give us clue - what's the issue?? errors? wrong output?

Comment: the issue is that m unable to run the code in the worksheet. I may need to redefine the function properly. I think the issue is that when the input is given in the mentioned manner. the compiler treats ";" as the end of statement, which according to me is the part of string..

Comment: Well you need to wrap everything in quotes: =ExpValue("Jan--01/June30;EXPO(2000),July--01/Dec--31;NORM(1000,2000)")

Comment: Thanks DJ,
Could you help me on another problem?? I need to calculate the number of days in the duration , for each duration. keeping ini mind the number of days in a month. like 31 for jan, 28 for feb , etc...
Like ExpValue("Jan--01/June--30;EXPO(2000),July--01/Dec--31;NORM(1000,2000)") , have 2 seasons. One from Jan 01 to June 30, and another from July01 to Dec 31. I need to calculate the number of days in both the duration. Any sugeestion??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DateDiff("d",FirstDate,SecondDate) '+ 1
```

Will give the difference in days between the two dates, "m" for months etc.
This will give you from first date, so will exclude it, so if you want total days just +1.

As for your code above, I got it working, but hard to understand what you are trying to achieve. There's probably better ways than passing the whole equation as a string.

```
=ExpValue("1/1/2001-30/6/2001;EXPO(2000)|1/7/2001-31/12/2001;NORM(1000,2000)")
```

I changed a few things in the equation to better identify the split parts in the string. Can't use "," as it is conained in the NORM(,) function.
So "-" splits the dates, ";" splits the function, and "|" splits the two equations.

Here is my attemp, the code should procude: ,181,2000,184,1000
Where 181 and 184 is the number of days between the two dates enetered. I believe the select case methods aren't working correctly either, but with a working function you can improve it.

```
Public Function ExpValue(str As String) As String

Dim Mylen As Integer, A As Integer, B As Integer, C As Integer, D As Integer, i As Integer
Dim j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Double, N As Integer, ExpectValue As Double
Dim Arr1() As String, Arr2() As String, Arr3() As String, Arr4() As String, Arr5() As String
Dim Arr6() As String, Arr7() As Double, txt1 As String, txt2 As String, txt3 As String
Dim txt4 As String, txt5 As String, txt6 As String

Dim d1 As Date, d2 As Date, ArrDate() As String
Dim dPart() As Integer

Arr1() = Split(str, "|")
C = UBound(Arr1())

ReDim Arr3(C)
ReDim Arr4(C)
ReDim dPart(C)


For i = 0 To C
    Arr2() = Split(Arr1(i), ";")
    Arr3(i) = Arr2(0)
    Arr4(i) = Arr2(1)

    ArrDate() = Split(Arr2(0), "-")
    d1 = ArrDate(0)
    d2 = ArrDate(1)
    dPart(i) = DateDiff("d", d1, d2) + 1
Next i

ReDim Preserve Arr3(C) As String
ReDim Preserve Arr4(C) As String
ReDim Arr6(C)

For i = 0 To C
    If Arr4(i) <> "" Then
    txt1 = Arr4(i)
    Mylen = Len(txt1)
    txt2 = Left(txt1, 4)    ' type of distribution
    A = Mylen - 5
    B = Mylen - 6
    txt3 = Right(txt1, A)    ' 1,2.3,4,... )
    txt4 = Left(txt3, B)        ' 1,2.3,4.,..
    Arr5 = Split(txt4, ",")
    D = UBound(Arr5())

    ReDim Preserve Arr7(D) As Double

        For j = 0 To D
                Arr7(j) = CDbl(Arr5(0))
        Next j

        Select Case txt2

        Case "EXPO", "POIS"        ' just one number EXPO(2.34)
        l = CDbl(txt4)        ' txt4=2.34
        Arr6(i) = l

        Case "NORM"
        ExpectValue = Arr7(0)
        Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

        Case "BETA"
        ExpectValue = (Arr7(1) / (Arr7(0) + Arr7(1)))
        Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

        Case "GAMM"
        ExpectValue = Arr7(0) * Arr7(1)
        Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

        Case "TRIA"
        ExpectValue = ((Arr7(0) + Arr7(1) + Arr7(2)) / 3)
        Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

        Case "UNIF"
        ExpectValue = ((Arr7(0) + Arr7(1)) / 2)
        Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

        Case "LOGN"
        ExpectValue = Exp((Arr7(0) + ((Arr7(1)) ^ 2)) / 2)
             Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

        Case "ERLA"
        ExpectValue = Arr7(0) * Arr7(1)
        Arr6(i) = ExpectValue

        End Select
    End If
    Next i

    If C = 0 Then
        txt6 = dPart(0) & ";" & Arr3(0) & ";" & Arr6(0)
    Else
        txt6 = ""

        For i = 0 To C
            txt6 = txt6 & "," & dPart(i) & "," & Arr6(i)
        Next i
    End If

    ExpValue = txt6

End Function
```

Comment: ***As for your code....what you are trying to achieve.***
the user will key in the string,I need to process the type of distr., along with the no. of days for the respective dist., for each duration. Then,i have to calculate the weighted mean of the distributions thus obtained. like in the above case, it comes out as {(184*2000+181*1000)/365}

***I changed a few things in the equation to better identify the split parts in the string***
I changed a few notations :
`ExpValue(Jan--01/June--30:EXPO(100);July--01/Dec--31:NORm(1,2);`
is the new notation.

Thank you very much Rory, for your help.

Comment: ***I believe the select case methods aren't working correctly either, but with a working function you can improve it***    Is there any problem with SELECT CASE statements?.. i have done a bit of changes in the code.. it seems to work well (select case statements) ...

Comment: So have you resolved the problem, if not just edit your question to your knew working function and any issues you are having. With regards to the Select Case statements, the only one that would error was the LOGN and I'm guessing because of the EXP function. Also, does the `DateDiff` function work with that date format you are passing?

Comment: Yeah, the problem is resolved, thanks for your help. I have made a few minor changes with regard to the Select Case statements, and they are working properly. I changed the date format to mm/dd/yyyy and now `Datediff` is working properly. Appreciate your help.